# How to rename columns in tableau-prep by using an external source for the names?

Tags: tableau-api

I have two tables in a postgres database. Table1 contains my data, but its column names are only integers. A second table (Table2) contains the column names that belong to these integers.

```
Table1

1 | 2 | 3
---------
0 | 1 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
...
```

```
Table2

ColumnName | ColumnID
---------------------
Column1    | 1
Column2    | 2
Column2    | 3
```

The desired output would be:

```
Colum1 | Column2 | Column3
0      | 1       | 0
1      | 0       | 1
```

I can not do the renaming manually, because in reality I have about 600 columns and I have to do this for multiple tables.

Is it possible to achieve this in tableau prep?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to check whether using the "Pivot" feature in Tableau prep would solve your issue.

https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-us/prep_pivot.htm